# Silverstripe TimeField - Hide Seconds

Tags: silverstripe

Is there a way to hide seconds from the TimeField in the silverstripe CMS?

```
static $db = array (        

        'StartTime' => 'Time',
        'EndTime' => 'Time',

    );

public function getCMSFields() {
        $f = new FieldList(
            new TimeField('StartTime', _t('CalendarDateTime.STARTTIME','Start time')),
            new TimeField('EndTime', _t('CalendarDateTime.ENDTIME','End time')),
        return $f;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$myTimeField->setConfig('timeformat', 'HH:mm');` - see [TimeField API docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/forms/fields-datetime/TimeField.html).